# VB.NET Enable AutoFilter in protected Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm trying to enable the filter option when protecting the worksheet but I couldn't able to.

```
         If Trial Then
             'add filter on header
             oSheet.Range("A2").AutoFilter()
             oSheet.EnableAutoFilter = True
             oSheet.Range("A1:A1").Style.Locked = True
             oSheet.Protect("SamplePassword")
         Else
             oSheet.Range("A1:" & colAlpha & count).AutoFilter()
         End If
```

This is the option I want to enable - which allow the user to filter even the Excel is protected.

[image]

As you can see, I tried to apply **[EnableAutoFilter]** in my code but it does not work.
Below is my sample result

[image]

The filter has applied, but I couldn't select to filter - only default to all.
Please let me know if you have done something similar before, I've been trying to google all day long and still no luck.
Much appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some additional research and found out there is a method applicable to the above question

[Worksheet.Protect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.protect?view=vsto-2017)

As here mentioned, instead of just applying Protect("Password"), you can define different types of parameters, as below :

```
oSheet.Protect("SamplePassword", False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False)
```

and refer to the documentation for reference to turn on / off on "Setting"